# How to add an y axis title or label even after hide y axis labels in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

It took me hours to find how to add a y axis label after I hide y axis. Basically, I wish to make a plot like figure 1 as attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQQ5D.png), so y axis shows label as "Individuals", and x as "Trait", and labels for legend as "Trait response", with 3 values, 0=low, 1=average, 2=high.

I searched various sources, and did not find a solution, so appreciating any help. My data include the following variables:

- ID: 1 to 25, and
- 4 main variables, each has 3 values, 0 (low response), 1 (average response) and 2 (high response)
  And I would like to make a plot like figure 1 as attached above.

My initial R codes as below:

```
ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = variable, y = PID, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red", "Black", "Green" )) + theme_classic() + 
   theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

It produced a plot without y axis label and legend labels as attached figure 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJgiT.png) .

Then I continued to modify my codes based on R CHEAT SHEET below:

```
ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = variable, y = PID, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red", "Black", "Green" )) + theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Trait") +
  ylab("Individuals") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Trait response", labels=c('Low', 'Average', 'High'))
```

It created a figure as attached with colors change not as expected and without y axis label [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOHBv.png).

The reasons I like to hide y axis label just because I don't want to display values, so it can be neatly presented like a heatmap, but then when I added label for y, it did not work.

Therefore, I appreciate if any of our members could land a solution.

I look forward to receiving your support. I can provide data if necessary; yet it seems there is no field to attach data via this channel.

Comment: Remove `axis.title.y = element_blank()` to show the y axis title.

Comment: Thanks Stefan so much. As per your guide, I now removed axis.title.y below: `ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = variable, y = PID, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red", "Black", "Green" )) + theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Trait") +
  ylab("Individuals") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Trait response", labels=c('Low', 'Average', 'High'))`. Yet, the result is not expected as it contains a vertical line outside the plot and colors for low, average and high are not red, black and green.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reproduction of the figure in the 1st attachment, you want to remove  y axis text, ticks and lines, and add an angle in the y title and x text. The `vjust` and `hjust` are for justification of the text to stay in their position.

You don't have to add twice a `scale_fill` function, since you can add labels in the `_manual` function.
Since you add more than 1 labels you can use the `labs` function to include them all in one.

```
ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = variable, y = PID, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red", "Black", "Green" ),
                      labels = c('Low', 'Average', 'High')) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0)) +
    labs(x = "Trait", y = "Individuals", 
         fill = "Trait response")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly now. I really appreciate your generous support and help.